# Voice catalog is not available in local storage for Here Maps Voice Instruction feature

Tags: android, navigation, here-api

Following the steps in HERE Android SDK Developer's Guide for **Navigation Voice Instruction**, I cannot start the Voice feature. The debug information is as below:

1. `// Retrieve the VoiceCatalog and download the latest updates
   VoiceCatalog voiceCatalog = VoiceCatalog.getInstance();
   voiceCatalog.downloadCatalog(new VoiceCatalog.OnDownloadDoneListener() {
       @Override
       public void onDownloadDone(VoiceCatalog.Error error) {
           if (error == VoiceCatalog.Error.NONE) {
               // catalog download successful
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Voice catalog download successful.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           } else {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Voice catalog download error.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }
       }
   });`

`onDownloadDone()` function will always receive an error: `VoiceCatalog.Error UNKNOW`

2. `VoiceCatalog.getInstance().isLocalCatalogAvailable()`

`isLocalCatalogAvailable()` will always be false.

3. A set of sample voice skins from sdk.zip/misc is copied to /data/app_namespace/files/voices-download

Could anyone suggest on this issue? Thanks.

Comment: fyi, I have found a temporary solution. In the code, `voicePackage.isTts()` will always return false. It checks the voice package TTS capability. I am not sure why it returns false. Bypassing this condition check, the voice instruction is working. Additional, it does not work if your project is built based on the examples from HERE Android SDK. You need to create a new project for your own testing. Correct me if I am wrong. Thanks.

Comment: 2 questions:
1) downloadCatalog(...) returns a boolean, can you check the result of that?
2) What version of the SDK are you using?  You should be able to find that in SDK_Info.txt of your evaluation package.

Comment: Also, it would be helpful if you posted a full sample project showing the issue.

Answer (score 2):

We find the following solution for this issue.

```
     private void setupVoice() {
        // Retrieve the VoiceCatalog and download the latest updates
        VoiceCatalog voiceCatalog = VoiceCatalog.getInstance();

        if (!voiceCatalog.isLocalCatalogAvailable()) {
            if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "Voice catalog is not available in local storage.");
            //Toast.makeText(mActivity.getApplicationContext(), "Voice catalog is not available in local storage.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

            voiceCatalog.downloadCatalog(new VoiceCatalog.OnDownloadDoneListener() {
                @Override
                public void onDownloadDone(VoiceCatalog.Error error) {
                    if (error == VoiceCatalog.Error.NONE) {
                        // catalog download successful
                        if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "Download voice catalog successfully.");

                        //Toast.makeText(mActivity.getApplicationContext(), "Voice catalog download successful.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    } else {
                        if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "Download voice catalog failed.");

                        //Toast.makeText(mActivity.getApplicationContext(), "Voice catalog download error.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    // Get the list of voice packages from the voice catalog list
                    List<VoicePackage> voicePackages =
                            VoiceCatalog.getInstance().getCatalogList();
                    if (voicePackages.size() == 0) {
                        if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "Voice catalog size is 0.");

                        //Toast.makeText(mActivity.getApplicationContext(), "Voice catalog size is 0.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }

                    long id = -1;
                    // select
                    for (VoicePackage voicePackage : voicePackages) {
                        if (voicePackage.getMarcCode().compareToIgnoreCase("eng") == 0) {
                            //if (voicePackage.isTts()) // TODO: need to figure out why always return false
                            {
                                id = voicePackage.getId();
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                    if (!VoiceCatalog.getInstance().isLocalVoiceSkin(id)) {
                        final long finalId = id;
                        VoiceCatalog.getInstance().downloadVoice(id, new VoiceCatalog.OnDownloadDoneListener() {
                            @Override
                            public void onDownloadDone(VoiceCatalog.Error error) {
                                if (error == VoiceCatalog.Error.NONE) {
                                    //voice skin download successful
                                    if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "Download voice skin successfully.");

                                    //Toast.makeText(mActivity.getApplicationContext(), "Voice skin download successful.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                                    // set the voice skin for use by navigation manager
                                    if (VoiceCatalog.getInstance().getLocalVoiceSkin(finalId) != null) {
                                        m_navigationManager.setVoiceSkin(VoiceCatalog.getInstance().getLocalVoiceSkin(finalId));
                                    } else {
                                        if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "Get local voice skin error.");

                                        //Toast.makeText(mActivity.getApplicationContext(), "Navi manager set voice skin error.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                    }

                                } else {
                                    if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "Download voice skin failed.");
                                    //Toast.makeText(mActivity.getApplicationContext(), "Voice skin download error.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                                }

                            }
                        });
                    } else {
                        // set the voice skin for use by navigation manager
                        if (VoiceCatalog.getInstance().getLocalVoiceSkin(id) != null) {
                            m_navigationManager.setVoiceSkin(VoiceCatalog.getInstance().getLocalVoiceSkin(id));
                        } else {
                            if (DEBUG) Log.d(TAG, "Get local voice skin error.");
                            //Toast.makeText(mActivity.getApplicationContext(), "Navi manager set voice skin error.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    }
                }
            });
        } 
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me with these steps:

1. Apply for 90 day trial [here](https://developer.here.com/myapps/create-eval) (should receive SDK package, appid, token and license key)
2. Download and unzip HERE-sdk.zip
3. Open HERE-sdk/tutorial/BasicMapSolution (I used eclipse)
4. Refactor BasicMapActivity namespace to my namespace from step 1
5. Update AndroidManifest.xml with appid, apptoken and license key
6. Update BasicMapActivity.java like this (updating com.here.jon.test with your namespace of course):

   ```
   package com.here.jon.test;

   import android.app.Activity;
   import android.os.Bundle;
   import android.view.Menu;
   import android.widget.Toast;

   import com.here.android.mpa.common.GeoCoordinate;
   import com.here.android.mpa.common.OnEngineInitListener;
   import com.here.android.mpa.guidance.VoiceCatalog;
   import com.here.android.mpa.guidance.VoiceCatalog.Error;
   import com.here.android.mpa.guidance.VoiceCatalog.OnDownloadDoneListener;
   import com.here.android.mpa.mapping.Map;
   import com.here.android.mpa.mapping.MapFragment;
   import com.here.jon.test.R;

   public class BasicMapActivity extends Activity {

   // map embedded in the map fragment
   private Map map = null;

   // map fragment embedded in this activity
   private MapFragment mapFragment = null;

   @Override
   public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
       super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

       // Search for the map fragment to finish setup by calling init().
       mapFragment = (MapFragment) getFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.mapfragment);
       mapFragment.init(new OnEngineInitListener() {
           @Override
           public void onEngineInitializationCompleted(OnEngineInitListener.Error error) {
               if (error == OnEngineInitListener.Error.NONE) {
                   // retrieve a reference of the map from the map fragment
                   map = mapFragment.getMap();
                   // Set the map center coordinate to the Vancouver region (no animation)
                   map.setCenter(new GeoCoordinate(49.196261, -123.004773, 0.0), Map.Animation.NONE);
                   // Set the map zoom level to the average between min and max (no animation)
                   map.setZoomLevel((map.getMaxZoomLevel() + map.getMinZoomLevel()) / 2);
                   downloadVoiceCatalog();
               } else {
                   System.out.println("ERROR: Cannot initialize Map Fragment");
               }
           }
       });

   }

   @Override
   public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
       getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.activity_main, menu);
       return true;
   }

   private void downloadVoiceCatalog() {
       boolean result = VoiceCatalog.getInstance().downloadCatalog(new OnDownloadDoneListener(){

           @Override
           public void onDownloadDone(Error error) {
               Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "onDownloadDone: " + error.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
           }});
       if (result) {
           Toast.makeText(this, "Successfully requested catalog", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
       } else {
           Toast.makeText(this, "Failed to request catalog", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
       }
   }
   ```

If you follow these steps, you should get a Toast with onDownloadDone: NONE at the end

Comment: @leon, care to post your solution for others?